# Azure Data Studio Database Project Failure When Applying Schema Compare

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-studio

I'm using Azure Data Studio.  I created a brand new project and updated it from the database.  Made a very small change, and attempted to apply back to the database.  I receive the error "The source login in not a member of the 'loginmanager' role. The comparison will be restricted to database scoped elements."

I tried granting loginmanager to my user account.

I tried turning off every object type except stored procedures (what I'm changing), as others have suggested turning off the security objects (for example, here: https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/21773).

The full error was:

> Apply schema compare changes: Error SQL0: Performing publish is not possible for this comparison result.
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The source login in not a member of the 'loginmanager' role. The comparison will be restricted to database scoped elements.) (Cannot generate deployment plan due to an internal error.)
> ---> System.Exception: The source login in not a member of the 'loginmanager' role. The comparison will be restricted to database scoped elements.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.Exception: Cannot generate deployment plan due to an internal error.<---
>
> Error SQL0: Performing publish is not possible for this comparison result.
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The source login in not a member of the 'loginmanager' role. The comparison will be restricted to database scoped elements.) (Cannot generate deployment plan due to an internal error.)
> ---> System.Exception: The source login in not a member of the 'loginmanager' role. The comparison will be restricted to database scoped elements.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.Exception: Cannot generate deployment plan due to an internal error.<---

Comment: Can you please see if the error still occurs after unselecting "Drop role members in source" and "Drop permissions not in source" in the Schema Compare Options?

Comment: Yes, the error message is still there after unchecking "Drop permissions not in source" and "Drop role members not defined in source" as well as only having only "Stored Procedures" and "Views" selected under "Include Option Types"